# Add Multiple table in one databasehelper class

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 2 table Employee and order table, I'm trying to implement those tables into the same databasehelper class, but is gives me several errors, should i create a another databasehelper class, or can i implement these to into one

tables are looks like this
`public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    private static final String DB_NAME = "shopinstyle.db";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "Employee";
    private static final String ORDER_TABLE = "Order";

    //Employee
    //columns
    private static final String ID = "ID";
    private static final String FNAME = "FNAME";
    private static final String LNAME = "LNAME";
    private static final String PNUMBER = "PNUMBER";
    private static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    private static final String NIC = "NIC";

    //Order
    //columns
    private static final String ord_ID = "ord_ID";
    private static final String ord_Name = "ord_Name";
    private static final String ord_Qty = "ord_Qty";
    private static final String ord_Price = "ord_Price";
    private static final String ord_Location = "ord_Location";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (" +
            ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            FNAME + " TEXT, " +
            LNAME + " TEXT, " +
            PNUMBER + " TEXT, " +
            EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
            NIC + " TEXT" + ")";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ORDER = "CREATE TABLE " + ORDER_TABLE + " (" +
            ord_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            ord_Name + " TEXT, " +
            ord_Qty + " TEXT, " +
            ord_Price + " TEXT, " +
            ord_Location + " TEXT " + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME,ORDER_TABLE, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ORDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ORDER_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

    }`
```

there is a error in this line

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME,ORDER_TABLE, null, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3d argument in the cal of `super()` inside the constructor of the `DatabaseHelper` class is `factory` which you can pass as `null` and not a table's name:

```
super(context, DB_NAME,null, 1);
```

Comment: It works for one table but what if i have two tables

Comment: You can have as many tables as you want. The call to super() is not about the tables but about the database.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: I understood and it works `private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ORDER = "CREATE TABLE " + ORDER_TABLE + " ` now i have a new error in this line `<database name> or <define table name> expected, got Order`

Comment: Order is a reserved word and you can't use it as it is. Surround it inside square brackets: `private static final String ORDER_TABLE = "[Order]"`